# Disable some context menu Items if multiple rows selected in TableView JavaFx

Tags: java, binding, javafx, javafx-2

I'm new to JavaFx. Is there a way that I can bind an menu item's `disable property` to a `tableview`'s selection property. So menu item get disable if multiple rows are selected?

I tried

```
mnuItem.disableProperty().bind(tblView.selectionModelProperty().isNull());
```

But it get disable for both single and multiple selections.

How can I disable a menu item in multiple rows are selected in table view ?

**P.S.** I know and tried to do that with a listener like below

```
 tblView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Integer>() {
       @Override
       public void onChanged(Change<? extends Integer> change) {
            if (change.getList().size() >= 2) {
                 mnuItem.setDisable(true);
            } else {
                 mnuItem.setDisable(false);
            }
       }
 });
```

but, it throws an exception *"java.lang.RuntimeException : A bound value cannot be set"*

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: A bound value cannot be set.
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:139)
at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.setDisable(MenuItem.java:380)
at myPkg.MyController$14.onChanged(MyController.java:393)
```

Comment: The listener works for me !

Comment: I'm getting above exception. What could be the reason?

Comment: This exception means that you cannot change the value of a property that has been bound to another property. Try removing the binding of the `mnuItem`

Comment: Thanks :) I have another binding for that. If you put it as a answer I will accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception means that you cannot change the value of a property that has been bound to another property. Try removing the binding of the `mnuItem`

Comment: Thanks. Yes there was a bind to disable property of the same menu item. Wehn I removed that it works fine.